# what are default integer values?

Tags: c, int, long-integer, short

I read somewhere that default floating point values like `1.2` are `double` not `float`.
So what are default integer values like `6` , are they `short`  ,   `int`  or  `long`?

Comment: I heard that range of `short` and `int` is same. so a value bigger than `int` may come under `long` but what about small values, as they can be `short` and `int` both.

Comment: By the way, these are normally called "constant expressions" or "integer constants". The phrase "default values" normally implies a standard value like `0` or `0.0` which happens in certain cases (such as defining a `static` variable without an initializer)

Comment: After reading the answers below, test yourself and see if you can explain why `sizeof(4294967295u)` < `sizeof(2147483648)`  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of integer literals given in base 10 is the first type in the following list in which their value can fit:

- `int`
- `long int`
- `long long int`

For octal and hexadecimal literals, unsigned types will be considered as well, in the following order:

- `int`
- `unsigned int`
- `long int`
- `unsigned long int`
- `long long int`
- `unsigned long long int`

You can specify a `u` suffix to force `unsigned` types, an `l` suffix to force `long` or `long long`, or an `ll` suffix to force `long long`.

Reference: C99, 6.4.4.1p5

Comment: what suffix for `short`

Comment: @kevingomes There is no suffix for `short`. But if you need it (and you usually don't because conversion is automatic), you can cast to `short`.

Answer (score 4):

Just if someone is interested:

C11 §6.4.4.1/5:

> The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can
>   be represented.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Suffix        Decimal Constant              Octal/Hexadecimal Constant
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
none          int                           int
              long int                      unsigned int
              long long int                 unsigned long int
                                            long long int
                                            unsigned long long int
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
u or U        unsigned int                  unsigned int
              unsigned long int             unsigned long int
              unsigned long long int        unsigned long long int
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
l or L        long int                      long int
              long long int                 unsigned long int
                                            long long int
                                            unsigned long long int
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Both u or U   unsigned long int             unsigned long int
and l or L    unsigned long long int        unsigned long long int
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ll or LL      long long int                 long long int
                                            unsigend long long int
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Both u or U   unsigned long long int        unsigned long long int
and ll or LL
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As for the prefix §6.4.4.1/3:

> A decimal constant begins with a nonzero digit and consists of a sequence of decimal digits. An octal constant consists of the prefix 0 optionally followed by a sequence of the digits 0 through 7 only. A hexadecimal constant consists of the prefix 0x or 0X followed by a sequence of the decimal digits and the letters a (or A) through f (or F) with values 10 through 15 respectively.

Comment: FYI, I used a modified version of your table [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24148306/1708801).

Answer (score 2):

There are three types of integer literals(*or integer constants in the standards terminology*): decimal, octal or hex and the rule are slightly different for your specific example `6` would be `int` but in general for decimal constants without a suffix(*u, U, l, L, ll, LL*) it will be based on which type can represent the value which is covered in the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.4.4.1` *Integer constants* paragraph *5* which says:

> The type of an integer literal is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented.

so for a decimal literal without a suffix the types would be the first of:

- int
- long int
- long long int

and for *octal* and *hex* the types would be the first of:

- int
- unsigned int
- long int
- unsigned long int
- long long int
- unsigned long long int

Comment: "Integer literals", not "constants", I think.

Comment: why 6 is `int` ,it can also be `short`

Comment: @KerrekSB: `C11` calls them constants

Comment: @KerrekSB literal is C++ it comes under the integer constants section in C99.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I always think these questions are about C++ when in fact they are about C. Indeed, in C the only constants are literals, so that makes sense.

Comment: Still, it might be wise to refer to them as _integer literals_, then everyone knows what you mean. "Constants" might mean a whole lot of different things in C, the term is simply not helpful.