# How does the integer overflow work in C?

Tags: c, overflow, arithmetic-expressions, integer-promotion

I am a bit confused about how is arithmetic calculations are handled in a fixed point environment.
Consider following lines of code:

```
/* unsigned short is 16 bit.*/
unsigned short x = 1000;
unsigned short res;

/* Case1: The following yields correct result  in res */
res = (x*544/100);

/* Case2: The following yields wrong result in res*/
res = (x*544); /* expected overflow here */
res = res/100;
```

So, my question is:
I can see why case 2 yields wrong result. But 
 - What is it that the compiler does in case 1 that yields the correct result? 
 - Isn't the arithmetic operation essentially the same thing in case 1? Except, it's split into two   statements?
 - Can I expect a different behavior from a different compiler?

Comment: In case 1, the math is being done in int-sized ''variables'', presumably these are bigger than 16 bits, and then the final result (which does fit in 16 bits) is put in your 16 bit short.  In case 2, the math is still done in 'int's but the first assignment doesn't fit in 16 bits, so it is chopped up during the 1st assignment to res.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to the usual arithmetic conversion being applied to the operands of multiplication and then to division, which causes the *short* to be promoted to a larger integer type for the purpose of the calculation and then converted to *short* on assignment.

The [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) in section `6.5.5` *Multiplicative operators* says:

> The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands.

We need to also note that the *integer constants*, `544` and `100` will have type *int*, we can find the details on why in the question [what are default integer values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382916/what-are-default-integer-values).

We then can go to section `6.3.1.8` *Usual arithmetic conversions* and we end up at the paragraph that says:

> Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the
>   following rules are applied to the promoted operands:

and we end up at the following rule:

> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can
>   represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type, then the operand with unsigned integer type is converted
>   to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

So the result of the calculation is an *int*

Using the `-Wcoversion` flag `gcc` but surprisingly not `clang` produces a warning:

```
warning: conversion to 'short unsigned int' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
res = (x*544/100);
      ^
```

This leads to what you term the *correct* result in the first case since all the calculations are done in as *int* in your second case you lose the intermediate result from the multiplication since you assign it back to `res` and the value is converted to a value that fits into *short*.

Answer (score -3):

The program first **calculates** the **right part** of the assignment, then **assigns** the calculated value.

In the **first** example it calculates the value **before assigning** it so `res` can actually store it.

In the **second** example `res = (x*544);` can't hold such a big value and it overflows.

In conclusion, before assigning the compiler does **not care** if you pass the bounds of short.

Comment: With arbitrary-precision-arithmetic?